# Class ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - trying to get rid of it

Tags: java

I am writing a program that will take user input for a random number and number of iterations. I am attempting to do a bubble sort on this (for my class I am required to do it with bubble and selection sorts). My initial code did fine till I worked to add in the portion to do iterations and then the selection sort. Now when I run my code, it will stop and give an error noted in the title of my post. The line it stops at is if **randomArray[d]>randomArray[d+1]** (the last line in the code below).

From what I have researched in my attempts to resolve this, it says the error is usually thrown when the array has been accessed by illegal index... or the index is negative or greater than the size of the array. I have attempted a few different things to fix this, but at the moment I am at a wall. If anyone can provide some direction, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number please: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();

    //Get user input for number if iterations
    System.out.println("Enter a number of iterations please: ");
    int numIfor = input.nextInt();

    //create array of random numbers
    int[] randomArray = new int[n];
    Random bubbleRandom = new Random();

    //fill in the array of random numbers
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        randomArray[i] = bubbleRandom.nextInt(100);
    }
    //Printing the array before the sort
    System.out.println("The numbers before the Bubble Sort: ");
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(randomArray[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    //Printing the array out after the Bubble Sort
    int bubble = 0;
    int sort = 0;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();        

        for (int c=0; c < (numIfor - 1); c++)
    {
        for (int d=0; d < numIfor - c -1; d++)
    {
        if (randomArray[d]>randomArray[d+1])

    {
        bubble = randomArray[d];
        randomArray[d] = randomArray[d+1];
        randomArray[d+1] = bubble;
        sort++;
    }
    }
    }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long runningTime = endTime-startTime;

       System.out.println("The total number of iterations is: " +     numIfor);
       System.out.println("The total count of numbers sorted is: " + sort);
       System.out.println("The total time elapsed was: " + runningTime);
       System.out.println("The numbers after the Bubble Sort: ");
        for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
            System.out.print(randomArray[i] + " ");

    }

    }

}
```

Comment: What are you inputs for `n` and `numIfor`? If `numIfor` is greater than `n`, then randomArray will throw out of bound exception

Comment: the `for` constructs at the end appear to be incomplete

Comment: N is the user's input for random number. numIfor is the user input number for iterations. What we are supposed to do is write this and then run it three times using "random" values of 5,25, and 50 for N and 10,100,1000 for numIfor (which is my iterations). Reading your response means this will never work since the number if iterations will be greater at least for the first required run of 5.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that `d+1` is becoming larger than the last position of the array. You can make sure it only goes up to the end of the array by changing the last for loop as such:

The problem here is that you are looping to numIfor, which is a completely independent value from the length of the array (n). This means that if the user enters a numIfor and n, such that numIfor > n, then your code is bound to throw the exception.

The solution to this is using the actual length of the array as the limiter value instead, as such:

```
for (int c=0; c < randomArray.length-1; c++)
{
    for (int d=0; d < randomArray.length-c-1; d++)
{
    if (randomArray[d]>randomArray[d+1])
```

This is assuming that you want d to go through all the values of the array. But the real takeaway here is that you should always try to loop to less than the length of the array (the -1 is there because you are checking for array[d+1]). This works best if you are trying to reach all the values in the array because it guarantees that you don't go out of bounds.

Comment: Thank you! much appreciated. I decided to re-write it to work a bit better as you suggested.

Comment: Nice to know that it helped! Good luck.